# Facebook Graph API Filter Search Results

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, types, filter

I'm using PHP SDK to get the results for a certain keyword within public posts

```
$q = "something";
$results = $facebook->api('/search/','get',array('q'=>$q,'type'=>'post','limit'=>10));
```

this query returns a similar result to this one:

```
Array
(
    [id] => id
    [from] => Array
        (
            [name] => Some Random Name
            [id] => id
        )

    [message] => Hello hello hello. something
    [privacy] => Array
        (
            [value] => 
        )

    [type] => status
    [created_time] => 2013-10-31T10:20:58+0000
    [updated_time] => 2013-10-31T10:20:58+0000
)
```

as you see the **[type] => status** section, this can be status, photo, link etc. I'd like to get only photos from public posts which contain the search keyword (in other words, search in public posts which contain $q and filter/get/limit 10 results which have only [type] => photo value)

How can i achieve this? I assume FQL can't help on this since i search within public posts.

Comment: did you tried FB Graph api debugger ?

Comment: if you mean the Graph API Explorer, yes

Answer (score 5):

No this is not possible at this time may be in future it may get implemented.

The graph api search needs the API end point as

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE

Here Possible object types are - post,event,user, group etc.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

The returned value what you saw are fields and "type"  status, photo, link etc are the fields within the returned data, you can however narrow down your returned fields by specifying the

`&fields=id,name,picture,type`  etc

You can see the docs here "Available Search Types" in the following URL

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

**You need to loop through the result and display the desired one as you need.**

Comment: unfortunately yes, that looping is the thing which i'm not keen on to do, but guess there is no choice than this at the moment

Comment: Thats correct we need to wait for some new features and I am sure FB will add these features in future but they just dont want to give everything all at a time.