# Filtering graph results

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using the following query:

```
/me/posts?fields=story,type,created_time,privacy,message,picture,comments.summary(1).limit(100){created_time,from.id,like_count,message},likes.summary(1).limit(100){id}
```

i am getting posts from a user and some related data; this works fine. 
However, i would like to get only status updates (type = status) with a non-empty Message field.

As a quick fix i have solved this programatically, but i find this crude. Is there a better way?

Comment: Aparently there is no better way.

Comment: I guess this stays for all filtering tasks in Graph API. You can use FQL though. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749893/facebook-graph-api-filter-search-results

Comment: FQL is being phased out, so that is a no-go.

Comment: True, but it's still supported for at least a year. If you *must* solve it and you won't need it later then maybe. Although I would also rather choose the ugly Graph API solution.